# Material-table export dropdown view broken

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-table

I am having trouble with the Material-Table library in a NextJs project. It works fine for the large part except for the export button which displays a very small and empty dropdown with no text visible. The options to 'export as CSV' and 'export as PDF' are still there and still work, and I am able to select the options due to some padding which makes the buttons barely clickable, but no text is displayed.
I have encountered a github page where this issue was raised but the solution basically said that this was resolved in a patch (which obviously is not the case here).

package.json versions:

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.23",
    "material-table": "^1.63.0",
```

**What I am seeing:**

[No text is displayed in the dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DSYH.png)

[As you can see, both li elements are present in the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2CvI.png)

**What I am expecting to see:**

[To see a populated dropdown menu as per the documentation..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkTRI.png)

**What my code looks like:**

[These are my 'options' settings in Material-Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZPB.png)

I have been searching online for a while and have tried numerous different hacks but nothing seems to work, if anybody has an answer to this it would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Trouble is that I have tried to recreate it on codepen but can't seem to be able to. Is there anybody who has had this issue before?

Comment: is this issue solved? @CodingTypo

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. After searching for a long time, I found the below solution. Add localization property as below.The issue got fixed for me.

```
options={{
      search: true,
      filtering: true,
      exportButton: true,
      sorting: true,
    }}
    localization={{
      toolbar: {
        showColumnsAriaLabel: "Show Columns",
        exportTitle: "Export",
        exportAriaLabel: "Export",
        exportName: "Export as CSV",
        exportCSVName: "Export as CSV",
        exportPDFName: "Export as PDF",
      },
    }}
```

Comment: I eventually moved to changing the library to material-react-table due to MT being no longer maintained, so I cannot verify your answer.... but thank you for your response nonetheless